# Remove duplicate from List of objects c#

Tags: c#

I have a category in my object how can I remove duplicates from each category if there is a duplicate existence based on each category in the list concept.

Please see my requirement below.

```
Category    Name
-------    ------- 
A           1
A           1 
A           2 
B           1 
B           1
B           3
```

Final Result should be like

```
Category    Name
-------    ------- 
A           1
A           2 
B           1 
B           3
```

Comment: Please share the code you have so far (a [mre]).

Comment: Or read [Enumerable.Distinct Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-6.0), and think if you can apply that to your list.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you have duplicates in there in the first place? Is it worth using a `HashSet` instead of a `List` to avoid adding the duplicates at all?

Comment: If your case is any more complex than this seemingly contrived example you might need [DistinctBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinctby?view=net-6.0) but note that it's a recent addition to .net; if yours is older you might need `GroupBy(x => x.KeyHere, (k,g) => g.First())`

Comment: Luuk mentioned Distinct, and it's right but note that if these properties "Category" and "Name" are in a class you made, and you haven't overridden Equals and GetHashcode then Distinct in its most basic form will probably do nothing because in C#s opinion all your instances are different (if they're different isntances with the same data, at different memory addresses). The easiest way to solve it is perhaps to change your `class` to a `record` because records intrinstically have equality checking based on all their inherent data. There are so many ways to skin this cat

Answer (score 1):

Caius Jard's second comment is the reply you really want.
You want to use the Distinct method : `var myNonDuplicateList = initalList.Distinct();`

But in order to be able to use that method correctly, since this is a class (which has more fields compared to List) you need to implement the Equals method.

```
 public override bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return  (x.Category == y.Category) && (x.Name == y.Name);
    }
```

Comment: The virtual Equals method [only takes one parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0#system-object-equals(system-object)). It might also be worth mentioning `IEquatable<T>` and `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: thanks @JonasH my bad, it only takes one parameter indeed.